# Update React Native App without App store

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

Recently i went through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/) link and give it a try and it worked.But can we update the web part of a react native app without code push on the fly(without releasing update in app store).I have my own server where i like to update the web part of my react native part on each time user opens the app in client device.Is this achievable if yes any useful links on it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'web part' ?

Comment: The js bundle(html+css+js) in react native app say index.js the home screen of the app(minus one for asking a question )......

Comment: heheh it's okay.. I always get minuses :p, I can't ask anymore no stackoverflow,, you can't update the web part, because when the apk file get generated. the web code doesn't exist any more, it's only exist while development... apk file is generated from java (or swift for ios development)

Answer (score 2):

There is no system that will do what you want. Your options are:

1) Use Microsoft's CodePush. This would definitely be the best solution, however, it doesn't allow you to host the bundle on your own server.

2) You could setup RN to look for the bundle on your server, but it would be slow and painful because it would have to download the bundle each time.

3) You would have to create a similar system to CodePush that looks at your server instead, compares the version/timestamp, then downloads the bundle locally and then uses that bundle for future RN launches.